# Foundation 5 Topbar not working consistently in rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation 5 in my rails 4 app. The topbar menu works fine when I send a request. I can hover the items and nested items no problems. Then, I click on one of the items, which has a link_to method associated to it. Sometimes it gives the proper result where my menu still works perfectly, but other times the whole thing freezes. This also makes the back button of the mobile menu disappear. Once I send a new request through the refresh or url, the menu works again.

Rails doesn't see any problem in the log file. My menu works fine outside of rails. I wonder if maybe it has to do with my link_to tag_helpers or the way I have set up foundation in my app?

Here is a quick overview on how the JS is routed for foundation. (The config they suggest on their docs)
views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
</head>   
<body>     
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>     
</body>
```

assets/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(document).foundation();
```

Has anybody else encountered this problem? Any good solution other than not using foundation 5 out there?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Foundation has known issues with Turbolinks, your issue may be due to that.

To troubleshoot that, you could disable Turbolinks and see if the top-bar still has issues.

Here's a simple guide: http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4 .

Beyond that, if you must have Turbolinks, and Turbolinks is the issue.  You can try adding jquery turbolinks as seen here: https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks .

If the problem continues to persist, the next step would be to check the order you're importing the javascript files (this matters with these Turbolinks / Foundation issues) and you may be satisfied that way.  <strike>I do not have an exact order for you to put them in, but if you search for "Turbolinks Foundation" issues you will eventually stumble onto some solutions.</strike>  This is not necessarily a certain solution, but it'll guide you in the right direction.

**Update:** Try this order for importing your javascript assets.  And, to quote the [source](http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2013/06/28/troubleshooting-turbolinks-with-rails-4/):

> Its important to put all the Javascripts to be loaded inside the  tag. The order of inclusion of jQuery is important – ensure you load jquery.turbolinks before turbolinks and after jquery. Include all your custom js between jquery-turbolinks.js and turbolinks.js in your application.js

```
// app/assets/javascript/application.js

//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require foundation
//= require jwplayer/jwplayer.js
//= require asset_videos

//= require turbolinks
```

*Note:* Look at [Alex Aube's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21294673/1026898) on this page for additional useful information.

Comment: Thanks. I just had the same problem, and that just did the trick.

Comment: @vanda Which part, specifically, helped you?

Comment: I actualy removed the turbolinks for truobleshooting. btw i don't have this issue with turbolinks on firefox 26. This issue happens to me in chrome

Comment: @vanda To anyone wondering, I too have only had issues in Chrome.  This was true back with Foundation 4 and Rails 4 / Turbolinks as well.  Including jquery turbolinks and adjusting the order repaired those previous issues for myself.

Comment: @AlexAube I updated the question to include an example order.

Comment: @AlexAube Glad I could help - and welcome to Stackoverflow.  So you know, the etiquette is to typically not take up comment space with thank yous, and instead simply 'upvote' the answer and/or mark it as 'accepted'.  The same goes for helpful comments (less the 'marking as accepted' part).

Comment: Just a final note: `= javascript_include_tag "application"` should be in head tags.

Comment: I am having this same problem with foundation 5 and rails 4, however I am not using turbolinks, and I am not using link_tags, just normal a href tags. Some of my rails pages will have no problem with the dropdown, while other pages that have the exact same HTML will have problems. There doesn't seem to be any pattern to which pages the dropdown works for and which it wont. Have you heard of or encountered anything similar?

Answer (score 8):

Ok. To go along with what Ecnalyr explained. (Which he explained correctly, and I kind of misunderstood for a little bit). This worked for me:

I kept  `= javascript_include_tag "application"` at the end of the body of application.html.erb

application.js is like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .

$(document).foundation();

//= require turbolinks
```

Comment: awesome. this fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

This works for turbolinks progressbar and foundation tabs, dropdown links, accordion

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

var ready;
ready = function() {
  $(document).foundation();
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: Works fine with drop down links. Thanks !

Comment: Fixed the issue for me, at seems cleaner than adding jquery.turbolinks

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced this issue.

Using jquery.turbolinks didn't fix it. Reordering the requires in the application.js didn't fix it.

Nothing mentioned so far here did the trick.

The [solution I found](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/4845) was to move the foundation initializer from application.js to within the body. I just put it below my _nav partial.

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```