# Trouble using Foundation and Turbolinks with Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, turbolinks

I have a header with 2 buttons : Login and Sign up [Like this](http://postimg.org/image/tfcwebeoz/).
When I click on one of them, a window appear : [window open](http://postimg.org/image/lv7gn2ks3/). For this I use the "Reveal Modal" of foundation ([Reveal Modal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html)).

My problem : If I click on link for open a new page of my website and try to open / close the Login or Sign up popup, the window is closed but this time the shadow stay ([like this](http://postimg.org/image/worax30rz/)) and I need to press F5 for this works again.

I use Rails 4 and foundation 5.

File _header.html.erb (View Partial)

```
<div class="large-12 columns header">
  <div class="logo">
    logo
  </div>
  <div class="infos">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="" data-reveal-id="login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="" data-reveal-id="signup">Sign up</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="login" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
  <p>
    Page Test 
  </p>
</div>

<div id="signup" class="reveal-modal roundish" data-reveal>
  <p>
    Page Test 
  </p>
</div>
```

File application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require foundation
//= require bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js
//= require home
//= require_tree .

$(function() {
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Turbolinks doesn't work very well with the foundation file. My solution was to use jquery.turbolinks instead of turbolinks. Removing turbolinks altogether would work if that is indeed your problem. I had a similar problem with the topbar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293051/foundation-5-topbar-not-working-consistently-in-rails-4

Comment: Thank you @AlexAube. Your post helped me to find a solution. I just have moved the `//= require turbolinks` after `$(document).foundation();` without install jQuery Turbolink.

Comment: @AlexAube so jquery.turbolinks actually replaces turbolinks?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem was Turbolinks.

Solution : Put `//= require turbolinks` at the end

```
//= require jquery
//= require bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js
//= require foundation
//= require home
//= require_tree .

$(document).foundation();

//= require turbolinks
```

Thank You @AlexAube for your help ! :)

Comment: This fix is misleading.  It *works*, by effectively disabling turbolinks, because sprockets requires need to be at the top of the file, and the turbolinks `require` ends up being ignored.  While I would personally agree that removing turbolinks is probably the correct answer... something like what @Murtza suggests (hooking into turbolinks page load to re-call foundation) is going to be a more *correct* answer here.

Answer (score 7):

This works for turbolinks progressbar and foundation tabs, accordion

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

var ready;
ready = function() {
  $(document).foundation();
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: Another caveat, this code needs to be placed inside the `<body>`