# Devise sign_out sops working after installing foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, zurb-foundation

I'm making a simple application and all regarding devise was working fine until I installed Foundation 5.5.0. After this, the sign_out button gives me the following erorr:

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

My code for the sign_out button is the following:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign out' , destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

This is the generated HTML:

```
<a data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" rel="nofollow">Salir</a>
```

My application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

My application.css

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*= require foundation_and_overrides
*= require foundation
```

My layout.html.erb head:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

   <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "foundation-rails" %></title>

   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

I followed this guide to installing Foundation: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/applications.html

As you can see my setup is very basic so my question here is why after installing Foundation it starts sending a GET request instead of a DELETE request to the server? And what can I do to fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance

### EDIT

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   devise_for :users
```

Rake routes

```
new_user_session     GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
user_session         POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
user_password        POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
new_user_password    GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password   GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
```

### SOLUTION

Fixed the issue by myself by modifying the layout.html.erb like this:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

   <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "foundation-rails" %></title>

   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> 
   <%# Doesn't work if I put the turbolinks and the application tags together as it was before%>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Comment: Can you post your routes file, specifically the Devise routes declarations.

Comment: @tagCincy I posted them

Comment: Does it work if you add `remote: true` to the link?

Comment: You definitely don't want the sign out link to be remote, unless you wanted to add an additional handler to catch the JS response and redirect.  Are you *sure* it's Foundation that's causing the trouble?  The first thing I'd do would be to abolish all traces of turbolinks from your app, then repeat a few incantations to cast out evil and lay down some protective wards that it might never find its way back in again.

Comment: No, @tagCincy, same result

Comment: @numbers1311407, I'm 99% positive. Everything worked fine until I installed the foundation on a new branch. If I go back to the original branch it works ok. As for turbolinks, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that, specially about the incantations and evil part haha

Comment: turbolinks automagically adds all this Ajax loading to your page that has the tendency to create very hard to track down front end javascript bugs.  My point was that it's kind of evil and should be treated with caution.  I just noticed [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150922/trouble-using-foundation-and-turbolinks-with-rails-4), actually, regarding turbolinks and foundation, which may address your problem.

Comment: @numbers1311407 Thanks a lot for the answer, but unfortunately it didn't work for me =/

Comment: Apparently all my delete links stopped working. When I try to delete a row I get redirected to show instead. If I change the ```link_to``` to ```button_to``` it works, but that only means that I have to make a specific style for that kind of buttons to make them look like links which still doesn't entirely satisfy me =/

Comment: I still think the better solution would be to remove turbolinks :-P

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foundation 5 Topbar not working consistently in rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293051/foundation-5-topbar-not-working-consistently-in-rails-4)